# Should I take permission from the game owner to provide a guide of the game

Tags: copyright, licensing, software, privacy, trademark

I am planning to publish a guide to play a game which is available for mobile platform like, iPhone, android...etc. It is a very popular game, like many millions play this game.

1. To publish the game on iPhone AppStore or google play store, is it required to take permission from the owner of the game?
2. Of course, I am making the application to earn money, so if I have to take permission to publish their content, do they ask for revenue share?
3. Overall, what are the best practices to start using others digital content.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your guide contains **any** images or text from the game then, yes you need permission from the copyright holder to reproduce their content.

You may also need permission to simply use the name of the game since you are entering a for-profit venture based on copyrighted material you do not own.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, how do I contact with them? Can I mail them or call? Do they expect any revenue share?

Comment: I can't answer any of that. You haven't posted what the game is... and I have no idea if they will want revenue. You need to figure out how to contact them and ask them directly.

Answer (score 3):

Getting permission from the game owner would be a sensible approach. If you get it, great. Then you could do it with the owner's blessing.

It's possible to do your write up without the owner's permission, but then you have to be *much* more careful. For instance, the names of games cannot be copyrighted. No one can prevent you from writing "A Guide to Bridge," or "A Guide to Chess," etc. On the other hand, some games are *trademarked,* in which case you will need to attach a TM (trademark) symbol when referring to them. In this case, see a lawyer.

You are also allowed to discuss the game itself "in your own words," but you must be careful not to "plagiarize" anything from the rules, or the official game description. That is, while you can refer to specific aspects of a game, such as building houses and hotels, the leash on copying is fairly short, as little as five words. This does not refer to five words in a common sequence referring to a single thought like "The United States of America," but it could refer to five words in an original or unusual sequence such as "I think therefore I am," by Rene Descartes, or "X houses and Y hotels," where the numbers X and Y define the number of houses and hotels in a certain board game trademarked (I believe) by Parker Brothers.

Comment: Thanks for the information. The game I want to work for is "Clash of Clans". I will really appreciate if you can look for that perticular game and provide some input.